# ¿Cómo puedo escribir de manera correcta try y except en python?

Tags: python

Mi código es este:

```
class Alumno:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.alumno = str(input("Introduce el nombre del alumno: "))
        except:
            print("No puedes introducir un número en este apartado")
        try:
            self.nota = int(input("Introduce la nota del alumno: "))
        except:
            print("No puedes introducir un texto en este apartado")
```

Esto no me funciona ya que cuando lo ejecuto en la terminal me permite cometer el error con el primer input. En el segundo input ya sí me salta el error, pero quiero que lo haga en el primero.

Comment: Entiendo que el problema es que esperas que al meter un numero en el primer input debería lanzarte una excepción. Lo que pasa es que un número puede convertirse a string, por eso no te va a lanzar una excepción. Puedes probar con `isnumeric()` para comprobar si lo que se ha introducido es un numero

Answer (score 2):

Estás empleando la técnica incorrecta.

Quieres pedir una entrada hasta que lo ingresado sea un entero. La operación básica para pedir y convertir es

```
numero1 = int(input("numero 1? "))
```

y puede fallar si lo ingresado no es un entero. Entonces, lo encierras en un `try-except` para capturar el error:

```
try:
    numero1 = int(input("numero 1? "))
except ValueError:
    print("Debe ingresar un número")
```

El caso es que el código anterior pide sólo una vez; nosotros queremos que siga pidiendo hasta que sea válido.

La forma más simple de hacerlo es encerrar todo en un ciclo infinito y salir de él cuando se cumpla la condición:

```
while True:
    try:
        numero1 = int(input("numero 1? "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Debe ingresar un número")
# Aqui ya tenemos el valor ingresado en numero1
```

Si la conversión funciona, entonces la ejecución continua en la siguiente instrucción, que es un `break`, que te saca del `while`.

Luego de eso, en `numero1` tienes el valor ingresado.

Ojo. `int()` sólo convierte enteros. Si le pasas un número decimal (con punto), falla.

#### Demo

```
while True:
    try:
        numero1 = int(input("numero 1? "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Debe ingresar un entero")

print("El valor ingresado es ", numero1)
```

produce:

```
numero 1? 45.0
Debe ingresar un entero
numero 1? jose
Debe ingresar un entero
numero 1? 45
El valor ingresado es  45

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Creo que esto no es lo que pide el op. Si te fijas, el pregunta primero el nombre y luego la nota. Y quiere controlar que el nombre no tiene numeros mediante control de excepciones.

Comment: @Pikoh. Me doy cuenta, pero con esto ya tiene material para trabajar. Además vale el título de la pregunta.